# Copying files from one directory to other in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to copy files from  one directory to other using "UTL" function.

> source directory = EXPORT_PPM_TEMP
>   target directory = EXPORT_PPM

I am saving all files names in a collections and looping through the collections and copying to target directory.

> name of collection = vc_file_name.

I am using below code to copy.                                                                        It is copying all files but some files are copying as empty files

```
FOR i IN 1 .. vc_index    
      LOOP  
  vc_lp_file_name := vc_file_name(i);

  Utl_File.Fcopy('EXPORT_PPM_TEMP',vc_lp_file_name,'EXPORT_PPM',vc_lp_file_name);
  Utl_File.Fremove('EXPORT_PPM_TEMP',vc_lp_file_name);

END LOOP;
```

what is the reason behind coping some files with content and some without contents

Comment: Are the files readable by Oracle?

Comment: Could you show us both the permissions of a "copy-able" file and of one that isn't ?

Comment: Did those zero-length files exist prior to running the above code? The comment on `UTL_FILE.FCOPY` states "Copy all or part of a file to a ***new file***." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @ BOB 
after processing file are coming to "EXPORT_PPM_TEMP" .all files have data at that time .but after copying to 'EXPORT_PPM' some files copied with no data

Comment: @Sylvian
these directories have all permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   in_file  utl_file.file_type;
   s        VARCHAR2(200);
   c        NUMBER := 0;
   out_file utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
   in_file  := utl_file.fopen('/scratch/fccus/dbDump/BT', 'rocs.001.001.06.xml', 'R');
   out_file := utl_file.fopen('/scratch/fccus/dbDump/BT/success', 'rocs.001.001.06.xml', 'W');
   LOOP
      utl_file.get_line(in_file, s);
      utl_file.put_line(out_file, s);
      --dbms_output.put_line(s);
      c := c + 1;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_data_found THEN
      utl_file.fclose(in_file);
      utl_file.fclose(out_file);
      dbms_output.put_line('Number of lines: ' || c);
END;
```